# Replace column A's value based on column B's max

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

```
ID  number  account date
1   00002   GA1     1/1/2021
1   00004   GA1     1/3/2021
2   00001   GA1     1/4/2021
3   00012   GA2     1/3/2021
4   00010   GA2     1/2/2021
```

Output:

```
ID  number  account date
1   00002   GA1     1/1/2021
1   00002   GA1     1/1/2021
1   00002   GA1     1/1/2021
4   00010   GA2     1/2/2021
4   00010   GA2     1/2/2021
```

Rules:

1. For the same account, replace all dates with the earliest date of that account
2. For the same account, replace all ID and number with the ID and number where the earliest date appears

I have done the first part of the query -

```
df.groupby(['account'])['date'].transform('min')
```

However, I am having trouble transform the ID and number columns based on the date column. I'm looking for an efficient way to do this.

Comment: in this case, do you really need those duplicate rows?

Comment: If you are looking for just those two rows, you can do `print (df.loc[df.groupby('account')['date'].idxmin()])`

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by account and date then taking the first row of each group would give what you require.

The next step is to join it back to the original DataFrame

```py
In [18]: df[['account']].join(df.sort_values(['account', 'date']).groupby('account').first(), on='account')
Out[18]:
  account  ID  number      date
0     GA1   1       2  1/1/2021
1     GA1   1       2  1/1/2021
2     GA1   1       2  1/1/2021
3     GA2   4      10  1/2/2021
4     GA2   4      10  1/2/2021
```

Comment: This is changing the date. I am not sure if OP wanted to change the date as well. Just the number with the earliest date not the date itself.

Comment: I believe they did. see their 1.